# How to check if my APK Third Party Libs are 64 bit Architecture compliant?

Tags: android, google-play, 64-bit

I am preparing my client's app to 64 bit compatibility requirement and I already had taken some action, for example, I have checked for native libs and created 64 bit equivalents to them. The last thing is to check 3rd party libs for 64 bit compliance (I think), and I really have no idea how to do it. Can I somehow unzip the jar files and check for specific .so files? Will it be enough?

Before when I was trying to upload my app bundle to test release I was getting a message about this 64 bit compliance, now I don't (since I have 64 bit lib equivalents). Could it be a proof that my 3rd party libs are already 64 bit compliant? Can google play store detect 3rd party lib incompatibility?

I have read a tone of blogs and topics about it, but none of them is deliberate about checking third parties lib compliance.

Thanks

Comment: i submitted an answer, hope this helps. let me know if it doesnt and i'll try to edit it :) goodluck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The playstore will tell you if your app is not 64 bit complaint, here's a link on some ways you can determine whether or not your 3rd-party libraries (as these are part of your application you are submitting, so you have to check these as well) are 64-bit compliant, from the google developer docs : https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, your answer had helped me a lot. I used apk analyzer in Android Studio, and beside my native libs (which already were in 64 bit folders, because I rebuilt the project in order to generate them) there are no others .so files. Also, play store, when I am trying to do a test release, no longer shows the 64 bit warning. So, according to your answer, I guess my app is now 64 bit compliant?

Comment: @Paulina you SHOULD get an email from google play about anything which isn't complaint, sadly i found this out the hard way :( but the 64 bit compliant issue only starts from 1 august and your app will not be removed, you will just have to do changes to make it complaint , if something is wrong

Comment: Out of curiosity, you got an email after you submitted the app to play store? And did you have warning during the submitting? I'm just wondering because I was getting this warning during the upload of test release, and after my changes, I don't anymore. I don't know if this is reliable sign, that, at least regarding 64 bit topic, my app is fine now or not. The worst thing is that I have only one release attempt, and after that I will not have the chance to fix the app, if it won;t be compliant :|

Comment: @Paulina it was a bit different for me, as this is already an app that's on the store and it's something we have to fix now with a new release soon to avoid any problems, so i can't really give you a definite answer :P

Comment: Sure, I understand :) Thanks anyway :)

Comment: no worries, all the best :) hope my answer at least somewhat helped